# Iterate over Nested hashes/Array

Tags: ruby

I have the following response code from an api call. i am trying to get the following data extracted onto my database:

```
Duration ("5 Hours and 21 Minutes"),
Departure ("From LAX at 2020/10/05 - 16:00),
Arrival ("Arriving in JFK at 2020/10/06 - 21:00"),
Price ("256.46"),
Stops ("0")
Currency ("Euro")
Cabin ("Economy")
```

My following code gets some of the attributes, but as i go i noticed it is getting very hard coded and ugly, and was wondering how would i make it better:

```
  res.data.select do |t|
    puts "Flight's total price:#{t["price"]["currency"]}#{t["price"]["total"]}"  
    t["itineraries"].select do |new_t|  
      puts "Flight's duration is: #{new_t["duration"]}"    
      new_t["segments"].select do |another_t|
        puts "Departue at: #{another_t["departure"]["at"]} from #{another_t["departure"]["iataCode"]}"
        puts "Arriving at: #{another_t["arrival"]["at"]} from #{another_t["arrival"]["iataCode"]}"
      end  
    end  
  end
```

The following is the response code from the api held in my variable

```
    {"type"=>"flight-offer",
 "id"=>"1",
 "source"=>"GDS",
 "instantTicketingRequired"=>false,
 "nonHomogeneous"=>false,
 "oneWay"=>false,
 "lastTicketingDate"=>"2020-07-31",
 "numberOfBookableSeats"=>9,
 "itineraries"=>
  [{"duration"=>"PT5H56M",
    "segments"=>
     [{"departure"=>
        {"iataCode"=>"JFK", "terminal"=>"4", "at"=>"2020-10-01T09:45:00"},
       "arrival"=>
        {"iataCode"=>"LAX", "terminal"=>"2", "at"=>"2020-10-01T12:41:00"},
       "carrierCode"=>"DL",
       "number"=>"653",
       "aircraft"=>{"code"=>"76W"},
       "operating"=>{"carrierCode"=>"DL"},
       "duration"=>"PT5H56M",
       "id"=>"30",
       "numberOfStops"=>0,
       "blacklistedInEU"=>false}]},
   {"duration"=>"PT5H21M",
    "segments"=>
     [{"departure"=>
        {"iataCode"=>"LAX", "terminal"=>"2", "at"=>"2020-10-05T16:00:00"},
       "arrival"=>
        {"iataCode"=>"JFK", "terminal"=>"4", "at"=>"2020-10-06T00:21:00"},
       "carrierCode"=>"DL",
       "number"=>"682",
       "aircraft"=>{"code"=>"76W"},
       "operating"=>{"carrierCode"=>"DL"},
       "duration"=>"PT5H21M",
       "id"=>"41",
       "numberOfStops"=>0,
       "blacklistedInEU"=>false}]}],
 "price"=>
  {"currency"=>"EUR",
   "total"=>"256.46",
   "base"=>"239.00",
   "fees"=>
    [{"amount"=>"0.00", "type"=>"SUPPLIER"},
     {"amount"=>"0.00", "type"=>"TICKETING"}],
   "grandTotal"=>"256.46"},
 "pricingOptions"=>
  {"fareType"=>["PUBLISHED"], "includedCheckedBagsOnly"=>false},
 "validatingAirlineCodes"=>["DL"],
 "travelerPricings"=>
  [{"travelerId"=>"1",
    "fareOption"=>"STANDARD",
    "travelerType"=>"ADULT",
    "price"=>{"currency"=>"EUR", "total"=>"256.46", "base"=>"239.00"},
    "fareDetailsBySegment"=>
     [{"segmentId"=>"30",
       "cabin"=>"ECONOMY",
       "fareBasis"=>"VAVQA0BC",
       "brandedFare"=>"BASICECON",
       "class"=>"E",
       "includedCheckedBags"=>{"quantity"=>0}},
      {"segmentId"=>"41",
       "cabin"=>"ECONOMY",
       "fareBasis"=>"VAVQA0BC",
       "brandedFare"=>"BASICECON",
       "class"=>"E",
       "includedCheckedBags"=>{"quantity"=>0}}]}]}
```

Thank you for reading through and trying to help. i hope you are safe and hope you have a great day.

Comment: There's no magical way to make this easier. What you could do is write Ruby objects that represent this data and then your access could be cleaner, like `flight.itineraries` or `departure[0].price.total`. The same thing can be achieved with [OpenStruct](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) if you want a quick solution.

Comment: By ruby object you mean, create a model with a flight class and have a self method in it that can be called and extract the info?

Comment: Exactly, yeah. That helps clean up the amount of syntax junk in your code.

Comment: `select` isn't the right thing to use here. It's used to remove elements from an array, and I can tell from your logic that you're not actually removing anything. Read up on [map](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map) and [slice](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice). Map is used to turn a list into another list of the same length. Slice is used to extract certain key-vals from a hash

Comment: Ty to both of you! I figured it out with your help.